# How to implement qr code scanner(mobile) in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, https, next.js, qr-code

I am building a website with scanning qr code.
This works fine on desktop but not working on mobile.
In Reactjs, this works with secure connection.
But in Nextjs, this does not work with secure connection.
I run custom server in Nextjs.

https://dev.to/nakib/using-https-on-next-js-local-development-server-bcd

This is my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { QrReader } from 'react-qr-reader';

const Home = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState('No result');

    return (
        <>
            <QrReader
                onResult={(result, error) => {
                    if (!!result) {
                        setData(result?.text);
                    }

                    if (!!error) {
                        console.info(error);
                    }
                }}
                style={{ width: '100%' }}
            />
            <p>{data}</p>
        </>
    );
};
export default Home;
```

This is error from mobile chrome inspector.
[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8o3M.png)

Comment: _"but not working on mobile"_ - What's not working specifically? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Thanks, juliomavles. Camera shows nothing. And I added error image.

Comment: It doesn't look like the MediaDevices API is supported in all browsers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices#browser_compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It's like your browser is not supported.

https://github.com/react-qr-reader/react-qr-reader#browser-support

Try this:

> **Browser Support**
>
> The browser layer is using the [MediaDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices) web API
> which is not supported by older browsers.
>
> *You can use external polyfills like [WebRTC adapter](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) to increase browser compatibility.*
>
> Also, note that the library is using the [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) (`Int32Array`,
> `Uint8ClampedArray`, etc.) which are not available in older browsers
> (e.g. Android 4 default browser).
>
> *You can use [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) to add support to these browsers.*
>
> In the PDF 417 decoder recent addition, the library now makes use of
> the new `BigInt` type, which [is not supported by all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=bigint) as well.
> There's no way to polyfill that and ponyfill libraries are **way to big**,
> but even if PDF 417 decoding relies on `BigInt` the rest of the library
> shall work ok in browsers that doesn't support it.
>
> *There's no polyfills for `BigInt` in the way it's coded in here.*